# Download source code of linux-modules-XXXXX-generic and build for another kernel version

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

How can I download the source code and build the `linux-modules-XXXXX-generic` for a different kernel version(No major difference in the version).

Comment: You can not. The code, module or built in, is all part of the kernel source tree. You will have to modify the specific source code and then compile the entire kernel. Perhaps give us some more information about your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The source code is the kernel source.

This is an Ubuntu specific trick to build separate deb packages for image and modules.

So if you want to build another Ubuntu kernel modules, you need simply to build another kernel.If you keep the Ubuntu build options, you'll get image, headers and modules.